# django cms static media files cannot be found (404)

Tags: django, static, content-management-system, settings, media

I'm new to django cms and I'm really lucky that I was able to install it. If I go to the backend of my site (http://localhost:8000/admin), then the django cms admin panel shows up.

If I want to edit some cms pages then I can see that the browser tries to get some files like "/static_media/cms/jquery.dialog.css", "/static_media/cms/pages.css", "/static_media/cms/ui.core.js" and so on...

Unfortunately the browser only gets a HTTP 404 response and I do not know what I have to configure in "settings.py" or "url.py" to get things working. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution at http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2401/